# $http response header message

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-ui

is it possible in anulgarjs to fetch the response header message?

in a code similar to that

```
$http.get(url)
    .success(){
         something
    }.error(status,"headers text message)"{
             alert(status+" "+"headers text message or a method to get it";
    }
```

in the alert i need to write somthing like that:
500 internal server error.
In the console log i can see the error status and text message,
what do i have to put in the error case? what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
  var data = response.data;
  var status = response.status;
  alert(status);
});
```

[See this document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

Comment: response.data is the correct answer i was so stupid, i even use it for the success method....:( thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can!
On success (or error) you have a callback with this parameters

```
$http({
url: 'url',
method: 'GET'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
});
```

Check the documentation
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

Comment: ok i wasn't so clear. I already have done something like that and it give me the status code, but not the text message and i need that too