# get the header error message

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

i don't understand excatly the headers element, when i write that function:

```
error(headers){
     alert(headers);
 }
```

the alert print the function, how can i do to reach element inside the headers?
I have thought to built an if case with the status code, but i cant't because the server that send the response isn't very well formed, and it send headers with the same status but with different message
Another idea that i have was to use html page of the error to get the message, but even if i success in that, it's not sure that the sever in question always send a standard page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem,
probably i will say something that's not new.
The solution that i have adopted it's that i have put, in the server, the error message under a variable, so i have use

```
headers('the variable as a string')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
  var data = response.data;
  var status = response.status;
  alert(status);
});
```

I have already answer, here

[$http response header message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038761/http-response-header-message/22039012#22039012)

Answer (score 0):

I think headers will return a blank object

http://plnkr.co/edit/FUu3izHg5xETTaB6V9C6?p=preview

The above plunker explains the header pass from the service and get it from config.headers object in the error function if thats what you are looking for.

I want to know as well what is the purpose of header in the error object